# Sum list of objects within list with Linq

Tags: linq, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.2

I have a list of Teams which contains another list of Players and every Player has played games number, I want to sum every played game that a player has grouped by Team.

How can I do a linq function to get that result?

I have tried something like that but I got stuck

```
var ListResultQuery = students.SelectMany(books=>books.Scores.Where(book=>book.Price>5).GroupBy(b=>b.Name));
```

My project Currently is:

```
    public class Team{
        public string Name{get;set}
        public ICollection<Player> PlayerList{get;set}
    }
    
    public class Player{
        public string Name{get;set}
        public int playedGames{get;set}
    }
```

Comment: Do you have team object in Player ?

Comment: Every team has collection of players with played games, so it is already grouped by Teams. Can same players be in different teams?

Comment: *every played game that a player has* -- That sounds like something different than simply tallying `playedGames` per team. That would require a `Game` entity. Also, how useful is the sum of players `playedGames` per team? If 10 players played in the same 10 games, it's still 10 games.

Comment: In player I have not object, and yes every team have a collection of player and players cannot be in different teams, is like a footbal team, you just can play in one team, besides the transfer market and those stuff that dont apply here, and like football you can belong to a team but it doesnt mean that you play all games, will be players that play more than others, so I want to sum every played game of every player in each group

Comment: a desired result would be helpful